# Console.log the event that triggered page scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I track down and `console.log` the event responsible for scrolling the page to top when content is finished loading? Note, there is nothing in the code that explicitly scrolls to top, but after the (jQuery) ajax content is successfully fetched and rendered, the page scrolls to top if user has already scrolled down a bit.

**Is there a way to log what's triggering this behavior?**

**Is there a Chrome extension that allow the logging of all Javascript events?**

Some things I've tried that did not help:

- no functions are run more than once (console.log shows once for each step)
- prevent scroll animation using

  ```
  $('html, body').stop(true,false).clearQueue().finish();
  ```

  doesn't help
- disable image lazy load plugin and other secondary plugins has no effect
- logging body height is correctly reported at each step of the ajax/callbacks
- adding `return false;` to `$.ajax().success()`,`done()`,`complete()` does not help

Ajax is triggered on document ready. The scroll to top happens after everything is loaded.

Comment: I'd venture to guess that your AJAX calls are failing to fire, set your debugger to "preserve errors upon navigation" and let us know what happens ...

Comment: @Xander, how would I set that in jQuery's `$.ajax`? There is nothing in on `$.ajax().error(function(){ console.log('ajax error'); });`. It seems like the issue actually occurs after ajax successfully completes.

Comment: Look for that option in Chrome/Firefox dev tools. After doing so, observe the error console for any errors that may be causing the behavior you're observing.

Comment: Thanks, I found it and turned it on, but there's no errors there.

Comment: The most frequent cause of this is an AJAX call getting triggered by an anchor tag with "#" as its href. The AJAX event is properly triggered, but without event.preventDefault, the hash makes the page scroll to the top.

Comment: How is the AJAX content loaded? Via a user clicking a link, button, etc...? Are you sure your javascript event handler is "return false;"? If not, in the case of a link, you will experience the scroll behavior you describe.

Comment: Nate, the ajax is not triggered by or tied to an anchor with href of "#". @loopforever, the ajax content is loaded on document ready (no clicks) and I've tried `return false;` on ajax complete/done with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As your source code is not complete, i can only imagine that it's because of your anchor tag on `<a href="#anchor">` element.

If there is no `name="anchor"` attributes, your `#anchor` tag will scroll your page to top.
To prevent that, try this: `<a href="#anchor" onclick="return false;">No more scrolling to top</a>`.

The other case could be that there is already anchor present in your URL, check it and remove everything after `#` character in your URL, i.e.: `www.website.com/contact/#anchor`, remove `#anchor` and try again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please check out my updated questions for more info.